# How to stop function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, timer, nstimer

So I'm doing little timer app in swift and I just have 2 buttons. One to start timer, and one to stop it and reset value to 0. I've figured out everything, and I have this function called timer which increases value for one each second for variable "Time". Problem is that when I click the STOP button, it resets the value to 0 but it keeps counting again.

Question is how do I stop that function from running.

Here is some code

```
var time = 0

func result() {
    time++
    print(time)
}

@IBAction func clickToStart(sender: AnyObject) {
    result()
}

@IBAction func clickToStop(sender: AnyObject) {
    time = 0
    print(time)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var timer = NSTimer()        
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your timer a member variable and call `timer.invalidate()` on it

Answer (score 0):

Change your variable timer to be an instance variable. Make it weak, since the system owns it, and when you stop the timer it will be deallocated automatically.

In your clickToStop method, call `timer.invalidate()`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out using the timer.invalidate() functions, but you can also use flag variables in case you are doing something else not related to time or want another actions to stop.

Basically, you can just create a bool variable and when the user stops the actions, make the bool true. In the other function, make it that if bool is true then don't do the actions unless it's false. This works well for a mute button.

Like in my game, when it's a game over, I have a bool variable touchesInvalid that is at the very top of the touchesBegan function. If the touchesInvalid bool is true, then the user can't do any more actions that involved touch.